# Local to global (and vice versa) matrix transformation of point in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

|Hi there. I have a problem with coordinate transformations from local to global coordinate system using javascript and three.js.

So to make problem simple, here is what i have.

I have locale coordinate system, translated and rotated in global space. Now, i want to draw a line in that locale system 
( using
  let lineGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  lineGeometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( points, 3 ) );
  let material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x293A45,opacity: 0.9,linewidth: 1 } );
  let line = new THREE.Line( lineGeometry, material););
)

line consist of four points.
for first two points of line, say point 1 and 2, I can calculate positions in locale system, but for other two points, say 3 and 4, I need to calculate position in global system. For point 3 i calculate position like global position of point 1 (global coordinates of point 1) and then add x,y,z additions. For point 4 i calculate position like global position of point 2 (global coordinates of point 2) and then add x,y,z additions.

Is there any way to recalculate points coordinates from local to global coordinate system ?

I tried to do that using matrixWorld.elements[12] , [13], and [14] comand, but that only works when i create new THREE.Object3D() and place it in the position of points 1 and 2. Then I can use matrixWorld.elements command. But that solution have 2 problems. First one is I put more load on processor by adding new objects, and second one is matrixWorld.elements command need 5 mili seconds calculate world coordinates of 3d objects, so i have to put setTimeout function, to continue to draw line after matrix is updated.

Also tried to create THREE.Vector3( 5, 0, 0 ) and to transform it, but didnt work.

So, one more time question is, is there any way to have point coordinates (x,y,z) in locale system, and then transform it to the (X,Y,Z) coordinates in global system ?

If anyone have some idea, ill be very happy, and thankful.

Sincerely yours,
Marko.

Comment: Take a look at [`Object3D.localToWorld`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.localToWorld) and [`Object3D.worldToLocal`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.worldToLocal). These functions can (destructively) convert a `Vector3` from one coordinate system to the other.

Comment: Thanks TheJim01. I tried your suggestion but it works only with Object3D elements. I cant do it without using Object3D. Or, I misunderstood something. So if I have code:   
 let element2 =   element1.localToWorld (new THREE.Vector3())                                     and if element1 is vector it gives error : Uncaught TypeError: element1.localToWorld is not a function. But if element1 is Object3D it works.

Comment: This is getting pretty deep, but practically every object in your scene is based on `Object3D`, and has two matrices (`matrix` and `matrixWorld`) that define its orientation in local and world space, respectively. To convert a `Vector3` from one space to the other, you need to do it relative to an object that represents the local space. For example, consider a `Mesh` at `(0, 5, 0)`. If you have a `Vector3` defined `(0, 5, 0)` and do: `myMesh.localToWorld(vec);`, then the `Vector3`'s new value will be `(0, 10, 0)`. It works the same in reverse with `worldToLocal`. Does that make sense?

Comment: thank you one more time TheJim01 . Now I get what you mean, with your example. Also, I tried matrix and matrixWorld, to get Object3D coordinates, and I succeed . Thanks !